# Division of $f(x):= x^6+x^4+x^3-x^2-1$ by $g(x):=x^4+x^3-1$ seems not so correct

Tags: polynomials

Let's say $f(x):= x^6+x^4+x^3-x^2-1$ and $g(x):=x^4+x^3-1$. Given that degree $(f(x))$ $>$ degree $(g(x))$, we can divide $f$ by $g$. The issue here is, continuous division of polynomial (starting from the higher powers) we have learnt in junior classes, at the end of the day, we get the remainder as $(-x^3-x+1)$ (quotient being $x^2-x+2$) but remainders can't be negative right? So, if we make the quotient $x^2-x+1$, I think the remainder obtained will be more suitable.

Comment: Polynomials aren't "positive" or "negative". In this context, $-x^3-x+1$ is a perfectly acceptable remainder.

Comment: `if we make the quotient x^2−x+1` ...what is the *degree* of the "remainder" you get?

Comment: Why shouldn't remainders be negative? And what does "negative" mean in terms of polynomials?  You really shouldn't like the particulars of integers influence your thinking when they don't apply.

Comment: @above(all), I get it, thanks!

Comment: @Mathejunior Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @gimusi Accepted, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The division is correct indeed we have that

$$(x^4+x^3-1)(x^2-x+2)=x^6-x^5+2x^4+x^5-x^4+2x^3-x^2+x-2=$$
$$=x^6+x^4+2x^3-x^2+x-2=(x^6+x^4+x^3-x^2-1)+(x^3+x-1)$$

and therefore

$$x^6+x^4+x^3-x^2-1=(x^4+x^3-1)(x^2-x+2)+(-x^3-x+1)$$